# Passing arguments via command line along with title

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

Probably the title has been used plenty, but I could not find the relevant help page/docs for my purpose
I am writing Python script that accept command like arguments:

input_script.py

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
        
def main(argv):
    """
    @param argv[1] : dataset in csv format
    @param argv[2] : file_name, default is saved as filter_data.csv 
    @return        : pandas dataframe h
    """   
    ## load the dataset
    df = pd.read_csv(argv[1])
    print(f"-->> Dataset is {argv[1]} of shape {df.shape}")
            
    ## Save file
    save_file_path = argv[2] if len(argv) >2 else "filter_data.csv"
    print(f"-->> The file is saved as {save_file_path}")
    
    df.to_csv(save_file_path)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Now, when I run this script via command line I run like following:

```
python3 input_script.py csv_input.csv csv_output.csv
```

However, I'm looking for possible library so that I could use it possibly following way:

```
python3 input_scirpt.py input_file=csv_input.csv output_file=csv_output.csv
```

So basically, passing the arguments along with their string.

Comment: [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), builtin module

Comment: @SUTerliakov you are right. Though I did check it out before shortly, I did again after reading your comment and yes, it does have what I want. Thanks!